# Show that the enire function $f$ is constant when the inequality holds.

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known for an entire function $f$, that there exists $a>0$ such that: $$|f(\exp(z))| \leq |z|^a+1$$ for all $z\in C$. Show that $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Please add your work so far - this site is not here to blindly answer your homework. If you show what you have done then people can help you understand where you are stuck. If you really can't get going, showing us the techniques your teacher has given you will enable us to help you get started

Comment: Oh im sorry, i was thinking that i would compare the answers with my work later. We've used Liouvilles theorem on the function given by g(z)=f(exp(z)) but we're getting stuck trying to show the inequality, we hoped that somebody could help.

Comment: People aren't going to post answers without seeing that you have put some effort in. You can click the edit button and add what you have tried to the question

Comment: Instead of applying Liouville's theorem, have you tried to apply the proof of Liouville's theorem?

Comment: Notice that for $|z|\geq2018$, we have $|f(z)| \leq C \log^a |z|$ for some constant $C$. Following other user's suggestions, you may open the gut of the proof of Liouville's theorem and apply this bound instead to obtain the same conclusion as in the original theorem.

Comment: If an entire function g satisfies equation of the type |g(z)|≤c|zⁿ| for some constant c and for all large z then g is a poly. of degree at most n. Now notice that exp has essential singularity at infinity and any poly. of positive degree has pole at infinity to conclude f is constant.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy integral formula, for all $r>e$ and $m\ge \frac a2$, \begin{align}&\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\lbrace\lvert z\rvert=r\rbrace} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\lbrace\lvert z\rvert=r\rbrace} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,d\theta\right\rvert=\\&=\left\lvert\frac{n!}{2\pi }\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})}{r^ne^{in\theta}}\,d\theta\right\rvert\le\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{( \ln^2 r+\theta^2)^{a/2}+1}{r^n}\,d\theta\le\\&\le\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(\ln^2 r+\theta^2)^m+1}{r^n}\,d\theta=\frac{n!}{2\pi} \left(\frac{(\ln r)^{2m+1}}{r^n}P_m\left(\frac{2\pi}{\ln r}\right)+\frac{2\pi}{r^n}\right)\end{align}

Wher $P_m(x)$ is the polynomial $\int_0^x (1+t^2)^m\,dt$. Taking the limit as $r\to\infty$ for any fixed $m\ge\frac a2$ we obtain that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\ge 1$. Since $f$ is analytic, it must be constant.

Specifically, the functions that satisfy that condition are exactly the constant functions $c$ such that $\lvert c\rvert\le1$.